# How to import contents of an external CSS into Django template directly?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a CSS file and I'm importing it to the page like below:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/common.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello world.
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to import CSS file's contents into the template directly. After this process, template should look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* this is the contents of common.css */
      body{ background: black; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello world.
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe there is a template filter or something like that. How can I do this?

PS: "directly" in the title means this process should done before the client get response.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your `common.css` file as an html file `common.html` containing all css properties

**common.html**

```
<style>
    // stuff 
</style>
```

In your template, you have to just inlucde it in your `head` tag

```
<head>
    {% include 'path/to/common.html' %}
</head>
```

Comment: I don't know it is the best way to do it. Maybe there is another option...